# What is the purpose of <rbc>, <rtc>, and <rp> in HTML?

Tags: html, cjk

According to [CSS Ruby Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-ruby-1/), one can create [ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_character) text with the following syntax:

```
<ruby><rb>one</rb> <rb>two</rb> <rt>1</rt> <rt>2</rt></ruby>
```

This document also mentions `rbc`, `rtc`, and `rp`. What is the purpose of these?

Comment: The question is about HTML elements, not CSS.The meanings of HTML elements are defined in specifications and drafts, but the question seems to confuse this with CSS. It is unclear what you are asking, and if you are asking for the purpose of ruby markup and its use, then the question appears to be too broad for SO (and you should consult appropriate tutorials or textbooks).

Answer (score 1):

`rbc` is a ruby base container. It contains `rb` elements. `rtc` is a ruby *text* container, which contains `rt` elements. `rp` is used to show content only in browsers that don't support ruby (See the SitePoint references: [rbc](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/rbc), [rtc](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/rtc), [rp](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/rp).)

Comment: So, I can use `<rbc>` instead of `<rb>`? When?

Comment: No, `rbc` would go around your `rb` elements. Look at the example [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/rbc).