# What is the CSS ruby-align property?

Tags: html, css

I saw an article mentioning the `ruby-align` property and I never heard of it. I checked w3schools to get some examples on this, but I couldn't see it mentioned at all.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp

I knew that `Ruby` was a new tag to HTML5 so I wanted to see if there was anything in the HTML Reference there.

I found out that ruby is used as an east-asian typography. I didn't find anything about its css properties there either.

I also see that Stack Overflow does not even have a tag for this property.

Does anyone actually know what this property does?

Is there any use at all to this property or the ruby tag?

Is there a reference anywhere that talks about this property? It's not on w3schools.

Comment: This is called ruby text. W3Schools does not usually cover such obscure technologies; the official specification can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby I'll see if I can think of a good name for a tag that won't be mistaken by Ruby programmers. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852016/what-is-the-purpose-of-rbc-rtc-and-rp-in-html

Comment: yes, I would like someone to create a tag for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend reading the [Mozilla Hacks article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/ruby-support-in-firefox-developer-edition-38/). I include relevant parts here:

> **Introduction**
>
> What is ruby? In short, ruby is an extra text, which is usually small,
>   attached to the main text for indicating the pronunciation or meaning
>   of the corresponding characters. This kind of annotation is widely
>   used in Japanese publications. It is also common in Chinese for books
>   for children, educational publications, and dictionaries.
>
> [image]
>
> **Basic Usage**
>
> Basically, the ruby support consists of four main tags: `<ruby>`,
>   `<rb>`, `<rt>`, and `<rp>`. `<ruby>` is the tag that wraps the whole
>   ruby structure, `<rb>` is used to mark the text in the normal line,
>   `<rt>` is for the annotation, and `<rp>` is a tag which is hidden by
>   default. With the four tags, the result above can be achieved from the
>   following code:
>
> ```html
> <ruby>
>   <rb>とある<rb>科学<rb>の<rb>超電磁砲</rb>
>   <rp>（</rp><rt>とある<rt>かがく<rt>の<rt>レールガン</rt><rp>）</rp>
> </ruby>
> ```
>
> **Advanced Support**
>
> Aside from the basic usage of ruby, Firefox now provides support for
>   more advanced cases.
>
> By default, if the width of an annotation does not match its base
>   text, the shorter text will be justified as shown in the example
>   above. However, this behavior can be controlled via the
>   [`ruby-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ruby-align) property. Aside from the default value
>   (`space-around`), it can also make the content align to both sides
>   (`space-between`), centered (`center`), or aligned to the start side
>   (`start`).

Answer (score 1):

> The ruby-align CSS property defines the distribution of the different
>   ruby elements over the base.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ruby-align). Sounds like it is experimental and only [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ruby-align#Browser_compatibility) in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like Mozilla is a much better source for documentation. The fact that it's experimental might be the reason why I haven't heard of it before. Either way, if it's only supported by firefox, looks like I can't see why it does.